# Undeclared identifiers (C-mex S-Functions)

Tags: matlab, mex

I understand that this is a very common problem that a lot is facing. however I don't understand how to link to my program. It's a simple c = a+b program. I have the following as my C-Mex S-function:

```
#define S_FUNCTION_NAME Addition 
#define S_FUNCTION_LEVEL 2

#include "simstruc.h"

static void mdlInitializeSizes(SimStruct *S)
{
int_T nInputPorts = 2; /* Set no. of input ports */
int_T nOutputPorts = 1; /* Set no. of output ports */
int_T needsInput = 1; /* Direct feed through = yes */

int_T inputPortIdx = 0;
int_T outputPortIdx = 0;

ssSetNumSFcnParams(S, 0);

if (ssGetNumSFcnParams(S) != ssGetSFcnParamsCount(S))
{
    return; /* If no. of expected input parameters is not equal to no.
               of parameters entered in dialog box, return. Simulink
               to generate an error indicating parameter mismatched */
}

/* Configure input ports */
if (!ssSetNumInputPorts(S, 2)) return;

/* Configure first input ports */
ssSetInputPortWidth(S, 0, DYNAMICALLY_SIZED); /* Set dimensions of first input port */
ssSetInputPortDirectFeedThrough(S, 0, 1); /* Set direct feed through */

/* Configure second input ports */
ssSetInputPortWidth(S, 1, DYNAMICALLY_SIZED); /* Set dimensions of second input port */
ssSetInputPortDirectFeedThrough(S, 1, 1); /* Set direct feed through */

/* Configure output ports */
if (!ssSetNumOutputPorts(S,1)) return;
ssSetOutputPortWidth(S, 0, DYNAMICALLY_SIZED); /* Set dimensions of output ports */

ssSetNumSampleTimes(S, 1); /* Set no. of sample times */

ssSetSimStateCompliance(S, USE_DEFAULT_SIM_STATE);

ssSetOptions (S,0);

} /* End of mdlInitializeSizes */


static void mdlInitializeSampleTimes (SimStruc *S)
{
ssSetSampleTimes(S, 0, INHERITED_SAMPLE_TIME);
/* Inherited Sample time: S-function block executes whenever driving block executes */
ssSetOffsetTime(S, 0, 0.0); /* No offset required */
ssSetModelReferenceSampleTimeDefaultInheritance(S); /* */
} /* End of mdlInitializeSampleTime */


static void mdlOutputs (SimStruc *S, int_T tid)
{
int_T i;
InputRealPtrsType uPtrs = ssGetInputPortRealSignalPtrs(S,0);
real_T *y = ssGetOutputPortRealSignal(S,0);
int_T width = ssGetOutputPortWidth(S,0);

for (i=0; i<width; i++) /* i = location of memory. from 0 to 1. */
{
    *y++ = (*uPtrs[i+1]) + (*uPtrs[i]); /* c = a + b */
}
} /* End of mdlOutputs */


static void mdlTerminate(SimStruct *S)
{
/* No task to be perform at end of simulation therefore no termination required.
   But this is a compulsory function to have for C-mex S-function */
} /* End of mdlTerminate */

#ifdef MATLAB_MEX_FILE
#include "simulink.c"
#else
#include "cg_sfun.h"
#endif
```

however when compiling on matlab, i keep getting the following error:

```
Addition.c:47: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
Addition.c:56: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from Addition.c:82:
/DIST/it/sw/amd64/matlab/r2010b/simulink/include/simulink.c: In function ‘_ProcessMexSfunctionCmdLineCall’:
/DIST/it/sw/amd64/matlab/r2010b/simulink/include/simulink.c:2545: error: ‘mdlInitializeSampleTimes’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/DIST/it/sw/amd64/matlab/r2010b/simulink/include/simulink.c:2545: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/DIST/it/sw/amd64/matlab/r2010b/simulink/include/simulink.c:2545: error: for each function it appears in.)
/DIST/it/sw/amd64/matlab/r2010b/simulink/include/simulink.c:2601: error: ‘mdlOutputs’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Any comments will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled `SimStruct` in the two lines mentioned at the top of your error message.  That error about the parentheses means that the compiler doesn't know that `SimStruc` is a type, so the * doesn't fit.  After that, those two functions aren't defined, so the simulink interface gets upset that it can't find those two required functions in your file.

Comment: Peter. Thanks for replying! however currently i have another error ---> mex:  Addition.c  not a normal file or does not exist. what does this means? i had added all required files to the path.

Comment: Are you in the correct directory when trying to compile?  Are you using the correct case for your file?  Linux filenames are case-sensitive.